# Change last key (dynamically named) in a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

If my array looks like:

```
$array['foo']['bar']['this'] = 'something';
Array
(
    [foo] => Array
        (
            [bar] => Array
                (
                    [this] => something
                )

        )
)
```

How do I change the value of [this] from something to something_else? The array can always have different keys.
Other examples:

```
$array1['test']['that'] = 'something';
$array2['yet']['a']['deeper']['example'] = 'something';
```

I want to change the last inner key. The results should be:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => Array
        (
            [bar] => Array
                (
                    [this] => something_else
                )

        )
)

Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
            [this] => something_else
        )
)

Array
(
    [yet] => Array
        (
            [a] => Array
                (
                    [depper] => Array
                             (
                                  [example] => something_else
                             )
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: are foo and bar dynamic?

Comment: Is it always a simple array as in your example?

Comment: There could be any number of keys with different names. It's always simple like this but could have more keys (like ['this1']['this2'][etc...]). Why downvote without even blinking?

Comment: I've clarified the question and given examples, please consider reopening and upvoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive call and access the array using a reference:

```
<?php
    function recursiveCall(array &$array, $newValue) {
        foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                recursiveCall($value, $newValue);
            } else {
                $value = $newValue;
            }
        }
    }

    $array['foo']['bar']['this'] = 'something';
    print_r($array);
    recursiveCall($array, 'tralala');
    print_r($array);
?>
```

Output:

```
//input array
Array
(
    [foo] => Array
        (
            [bar] => Array
                (
                    [this] => something
                )

        )

)

//output array
Array
(
    [foo] => Array
        (
            [bar] => Array
                (
                    [this] => tralala
                )

        )

)
```

This would work with any dimension and any `key` name.

Comment: I think you will have to match key names as well and add a break when the key is found and editing is done. Look at [this demo](https://3v4l.org/OELvi), it updates all keys that are not arrays.

Comment: @vivek_23, as OP says, the key name is dynamic, so it's quite enough to know that the respective key is not an array. Simply it would be wrong to match any key name.

Comment: But I feel it's incorrect or weird to update every key name that is not an array in itself. Anyways, will clarify this from OP.

Comment: @LWC Does [this demo](https://3v4l.org/OELvi) apply as a valid example for your case? What is the actual expected output for the array in the link?

Comment: Like @mitkosoft mentioned, the key name is dynamic. My specific scenario has only one key which is not an array, so I've accepted the answer. I guess for other scenarios you might need a way to also identify the last key among the non arrays keys.

Answer (score 1):

If foo and bar are not dynamic, you can do like this

```
$variable = "key";

$array['foo']['bar'][$variable] = 'something';
```

Comment: They are dynamic and the number of keys is undetermined.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array['foo']['bar']['this'] = 'something';
```

Since the keys for the above can be dynamic, You can use [`array_keys()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) repeatedly.

```
<?php

$array['foo']['bar']['this'] = 'something';

$key1 = array_keys($array)[0];
$key2 = array_keys($array[$key1])[0];
$key3 = array_keys($array[$key1][$key2])[0];

$array[$key1][$key2][$key3] = 'new thing';
print_r($array);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/T2vc1

Comment: Unfortunately, the number of keys is undetermined.

Comment: @LWC ok, you didn't state that first. Looking at your array, it seems to be only 3 levels deep. Also, using a while loop is a better idea than recursion.